# Criar um vetor com os Levels de um factor em r

Tags: array, r

Eu tenho uma coluna na minha matriz de dados da seguinte forma:
`> as.factor(matriz$especime)
  [1] 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3 
 [29] 3  3  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  7  7  7  7  7  7 
 [57] 7  7  7  7  7  7  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  10
 [85] 10 10 10 10 10 10 11 11 11 11 11 13 13 13 13 13 15 15
46 Levels: 1 2 3 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 13 15`

E preciso do vetor de Levels, isso é:
`1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 15`
 Pois ele não é uma sequencia de completa, falta alguns números.

Entretanto não consigo separa-lo.
Há alguma forma fácil de fazer isso?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pode-se simplificar o código do @WillianVieira. No código que se segue não é usado `unique`, só `levels` para extrair diretamente os níveis do fator.
Vou usar o mesmo exemplo de dados.

```
x <- as.factor(rep(1:13, 4))

as.numeric(levels(x))
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13
```

Answer (score 5):

Você pode usar a função `unique()`:

```
x <- as.factor(rep(1:13, 4))
x
# [1] 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12
# [26] 13 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11
# [51] 12 13
# Levels: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13

levs <- as.numeric(unique(x))
levs
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13

class(levs)
# [1] "numeric"
```